# How to take screenshot and send to server in android?

Tags: android, button, screenshot

i am trying to implement screenshot mechanism but i don't know how to do it.My requirement is i have one `edittext` and `Button`. When i click one button first take screen shot and send that screenshot to server through REST API call in android. how to do it?

Comment: take screen shot is ok, but i want to send that image to server immediately?

Comment: What have tried out so far about sending an image to a server using REST API? Getting answers to homework questions are not encouraged on SO.

Comment: If screenshot is OK, please check out this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/